# How can I make this proof more precise / detect the small error

Tags: general-topology, analysis

For a presentation seminar I had to give a mathetmatical presentation, and amongst others I explained the following lemma with accompanying proof:

Let $G:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, where $I$ is an interval. For any compact interval $I_1 \subset G(I)$ there is a compact interval $Q \subset I$ such that $G(Q) = I_1$.

Proof:

Let $I_1 = [G(p), G(q)]$, where $p,q \in I$. if $p < q$, let $r$ be the last point of $[p, q]$ where $G(r) = G(p)$ and let $s$ be the first point after $r$ where $G(s) = G(q)$. Then $G([r,s]) = I_1$. Similar reasoning applies when $p < q$.

To me this is quite a clear proof. I've no formal education in Topology yet however, and some dicussion arose over the use of 'the last point of $[p, q]$', in which some said the intervals needed a refinement. Being quite out of my safe zone however, I could not, and still cannot point to what would need refinement. To me it all looks OK. Do you guys have any insight to what I should change?

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: "the last point" where $G(r) = G(p)$ means the $r = \sup \{x \in [p,q] \mid G(x) = G(p)\}$. Why does this $\sup$ exist? Why does it satisfy $G(r) = G(p)$ (here you need continuity of $G$)? You should also note that it could happen that there is no point "after $r$" that satisfies $G(s) = G(q)$, i.e. if all those points lie "before $r$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the case where $G(x) = sin(1/x)$ and $I=(0,1)$.  Then $I_1 = [-1,1] \subseteq G(I)$.  Unfortunately there are infinitely many points in $I$ that map to $1$ (and $-1$).  So "the last point" is really not clearly defined.

After you fixed that you should also mention that you are using the intermediate value theorem to show that $G([r,s]) = I$.

I would start the proof like this:

Let $I_1 = [a,b]$ and $P = \{ x \in I \mid G(x) = a \}$ and $Q= \{ x\in I \mid G(x) = b \}$. ($P$ and $Q$ can be infinite as in the example above.)  Choose an element $p\in P$ and $q\in Q$ such that $[p,q]$ contains no other point of $P$ or $Q$ (**).  Then $G(x) \in I_1$ for any $x \in [p,q]$ (if not, then by the intermediate value theorem you would have another element of $P$ or $Q$ in $[p,q]$).  So $G([p,q]) \subseteq I_1$.  The statement $I_1 \subseteq G([p,q])$ follows by the intermediate value theorem as well.

**: Show that such interval $[p,q]$ exists:  We pick arbitrary points $p' \in P$ and $q' \in Q$. Wlog $p' < q'$. Then $[p',q']$ can still contain other points of $P$ and $Q$. Then define $p$ to be the supremum of $P \cap [p', q']$.  Since $[p', q']$ is compact this sup exists and lies in $[p', q']$.  So $[p, q']$ has no other points of $P$.  Now let $q$ be the infimum of $Q \cap [p,q']$.  Again, this exists since the interval is compact.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really clear answer! I'm interested though, how can you be sure that there is in fact a $[p, q]$ such that it contains no other point of $P$ or $Q$? Using "pick the first $p$ or $q$ to the right or left of ..."-type arguments you get the same issue, because $P$ and $Q$ can still be infinite..

Comment: Good point. Let me think about this for a bit.

Comment: @Rozemarijntje: See edits ** above.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would phrase what is probably the same idea.

The preimage of $G^{-1}(Q)$ is compact, so each of its connected components is a compact interval in $I$. For a given connected component $[a,b]$, we know that the image is compact and connected, so the image is a closed interval $[G(a),G(b)] \subseteq Q$. If this containment is proper, then some endpoint, say $G(b)$, is contained in the interior of $Q$. By continuity, there is a neighborhood of $b$ that is mapped into the interior of $Q$, which implies that $b$ was not the endpoint of that connected component of $G^{-1}(Q)$ - a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Is something unclear?

Comment: Is the preimage of a compact set under a continuous map always compact?  I don't think that's true.

Comment: @steffens21 A compact set is closed in a Hausdorff space, so it's preimage is closed. Since the domain is compact, it follows that the preimage is compact. (A closed subset F of a compact subset K is compact - any open covering of F can be extended to an open covering of K by adding $K \setminus F$. Then, remove $K \setminus F$ from the finite subcovering of $K$.)

Comment: Sure, but in the problem the domain is said to be an interval $I$.   And your argument only works if the domain is compact, right?  So what if the interval is, say, $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: @steffens21 I confess that I thought $I = [0,1]$ in this question.